# all possible matched pairs and associated information

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a txt file as input in which there are 3 columns divided by "," (ID, info1 and info2). I'd like to obtained an output in which there are all possible unique matched pairs based on the ID. To each match pairs all relative information should be associated.

input.txt

```
Id,info1,info2
6,7.2,79.16
7,6.6,78.93
8,6.1,78.06
```

output.txt

```
ID1,ID2,info1.1,info1.2,info2.1,info2.2 
6,7,7.2,6.6,79.16,78.93
6,8,7.2,6.1,79.16,78.06
7,8,6.6,6.1,78.93,78.06
```

How I can do that? Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Some perl, with [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) from CPAN:

```bsh
perl -MList::MoreUtils=zip -F, -lne '
    next if $. == 1;
    push @lines, [@F];
} END {
    print "id1,id2,info1.1,info1.2,info2.1,info2.2";
    for ($i = 0; $i < @lines - 1; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i+1; $j < @lines; $j++) {
            print join ",", zip @{$lines[$i]}, @{$lines[$j]};
        }
    }
' input.txt
```

Comment: Can't locate List/MoreUtils.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /apps/perlmodules /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: That's why I said "from CPAN" -- the module needs a separate installation.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe do it as a database table self-join, using `csvsql` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
csvsql --no-inference --query '
  SELECT a.Id AS ID1, b.Id AS ID2, a.info1 AS [info1.1], b.info1 AS [info1.2], a.info2 AS [info2.1], b.info2 AS [info2.2] 
  FROM input a JOIN input b ON a.Id < b.Id
' input.txt
ID1,ID2,info1.1,info1.2,info2.1,info2.2
6,7,7.2,6.6,79.16,78.93
6,8,7.2,6.1,79.16,78.06
7,8,6.6,6.1,78.93,78.06
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ map[NR] = $0 }
END {
    n = split(map[1],a)
    printf "%s%s%s%s", "ID1", OFS, "ID2", (k<n ? OFS : ORS)
    for ( k=2; k<=n; k++ ) {
        printf "%s.1%s%s.2%s", a[k], OFS, a[k], (k<n ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    for ( i=2; i<=NR; i++ ) {
        split(map[i],a)
        for ( j=i+1; j<=NR; j++ ) {
            split(map[j],b)
            for ( k=1; k<=n; k++ ) {
                printf "%s%s%s%s", a[k], OFS, b[k], (k<n ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
ID1,ID2,info1.1,info1.2,info2.1,info2.2
6,7,7.2,6.6,79.16,78.93
6,8,7.2,6.1,79.16,78.06
7,8,6.6,6.1,78.93,78.06
```